# Web Scraping using Node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape some data from a website and show it on my own website using Node js. I have written a file which is working fine. I could print it to the console to verify that. I want to show the data in my web page as an HTML element.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 
async function scrapeData(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page =await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    
    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="gatsby-focus-wrapper"]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent')
    const var= await txt.jsonValue();

    console.log({var});
    
    browser.close();
}
scrapeData('webpageToScrape');
```

I want to display the 'var' variable in my HTML page as a text. How can I achieve that? How can I link the Node.js script to my static HTML page?

Comment: How are you currently serving your HMTL?

Comment: My HTML page is served in a Linux based web server.

Comment: I meant from a NodeJS perspective, are you using native `http` module? `express`? `koa`? etc.

Comment: I am using express.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template engine like pug or ejs to render the page.

return the var variable in the function

If you are using express then

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
scrapeData('your url').then((resolve)=>{
res.render('link to the template file', {scrapedData: resolve})
})
})
```